# How to create a file with the user input name?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a textbox to get user input and a button.
When user fill the textbox and click the button,it will create a file
with the name of the text from the textbox.

I tried using

system.IO.File.Create and system.IO.File.Rename

but did not work.

Comment: what is the problem or error?

Comment: The problem is I cannot create the file with the name user entered into the textbox
like : system.IO.File.Create(@"c::\textbox.Text");

Comment: share your code as a minimum reproducible example so that people may help

Comment: Are you passing the full path or just the file name to system.IO.File.Create? it needs whole file path to create a file. If you are passing the full path then check if the app has access to the folder where you are creating the file.

Comment: @Nwecomer you need to do it like this ``system.IO.File.Create(@"c:\" + textbox.Text);``

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  System.IO.File.Create(@"c:\Users\Acer\source\repos\User data\textBox.Text"); }

that is how I want but I can't actually do it .Since it is inside " ",I can't access to textbox control.
Sorry,if it is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your problem as you wrote in the comments use this:

```
System.IO.File.Create(@"C:\" + textbox.Text);
```

You cant use textbox.Text inside of brackets to get the text from it, add a plus if you are using it from inside the textbox

Here is also a link to some useful documentation: [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-create-a-file-or-folder)

Comment: no problem everyone learns at their own pace :D